# CKEditor custom plugin in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have CKEditor 4 working in AngularJS and I created custom plugins for CKEditor before but I'm having trouble accessing the scope in angularjs.  The parts involved are:

> 1. The ckeditor directive - creates an attribute and binds to model
> 2. The controller for the directive
> 3. The plugin code - which needs to run something in the controller

I'm having trouble with the 3rd part.  Here's the code.  first is the directive

```
function ckeditor() {
    return {
        controller: HTMLEditorCtrl,
        controllerAs: 'htmlEditorCtrl',
        bindToController: true,
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
            editorOptions = {...
                extraPlugins: 'help'
            }
            var ckeditor = element.ckeditor(editorOptions);
            //ckeditor.setData = ngModel.$modelValue;

            // update ngModel on change
            ckeditor.editor.on('change', function () {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(this.getData());
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then a simple controller

```
HTMLEditorCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "$rootScope"];
function HTMLEditorCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.openHelp = openHelp;

    function openHelp() {
        var x = 1;
        // HERE'S where I want to do stuff
    }
}
```

And the plugin - which works and is in a separate file, except that I can't find a way to fire the controller function.

```
(function () {
var cmd = {
    canUndo: false, 
    exec: function (editor) {
        alert("open help");  // works
        // none of these references work
        var x = $scope;
        var x = $rootScope;
        var x = vm;
        ...
    }
};

CKEDITOR.plugins.add('help', {
    icons: 'help',
    init: function (editor) {
        // this fires when the editor loads
        editor.addCommand('help', cmd);
        editor.ui.addButton('help', { label: 'Help', command: 'help', toolbar: 'help' });
    }
});
})();
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find a solution for the scenario I posted but I did find a way of doing this that works in angularjs.  Basically the plugin file code has to be moved to the directive.  So before the code that initializes the editor instance I added...

```
if (!CKEDITOR.plugins.registered['help']) {
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add('help', {
        icons: 'help',
        init: function (editor) {
            editor.addCommand('help', {
                exec: function (editor) {
                    scope.htmlEditorCtrl.openHelp();
                }
            });
            editor.ui.addButton('help', { label: 'Help', command: 'help', toolbar: 'help' });
        }
    });
}
```

Then in the editor options I include extraPlugins = 'help'

And just for good messure at the start of the directive I added some clean up

```
for (name in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[name].destroy(true);
}
```